# Magento Add to Wishlist code not working

Tags: php, magento

I am using this snippet of code to add a wishlist to my product view

```
<a onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>')"
 class="buttons-wish" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>"></a>
<a onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ?>')"
 class="buttons-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>"></a>
```

But for some reason it is not working.

I need help to resolve the issue

Comment: Every good StackOverflow question that states a problem states what actually the problem is. Please explain the problem `is not working` is not an exact definition of a problem.

Comment: I mean: What exactly is the difference between what you want and what you get?

Comment: the code in addto.phtml was commented out so I uncommented it but I still do not see add to wishlist in my product view

Comment: I want add to wishlist in my product view

Answer (score 4):

Try this one.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>                                                    
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a>
```

Comment: in my case the wishlist URL always generates with https:// instead of http;// How can I prevent that? Recently we disabled the https:// from the site

Answer (score 0):

Check in the backend `System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced->Disable Modules Output`
Mage_Wishlist is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I found with the wishlist in Magento 1.8 is to do with the new form_key parameter, maybe this is what's caused the problem for you.

Magento 1.8 introduces form keys (they may have existed prior to 1.8 in some form, but now they're everywhere). They are mandatory if you want any of your forms to do anything. Want to add to cart / wishlist / comparison list? Need a form key. Want to submit a contact form? Need a form key. Want to log in? Form key. Etc.

All the necessary core templates have been updated to include this key as a hidden input element - in my experience you just need to copy and paste this line from any of a dozen different places into any custom templates you have (somewhere inside the form element) and they'll be fine too.

So all's well - a further security enhancement / spam prevention feature, and easy enough to accommodate.

The problem is that `$this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product)` generates a URL that *also* contains this form key, e.g. `/wishlist/index/add/product/101/form_key/xyz` which simply doesn't work. And in this case, by "doesn't work", I mean the "add to wishlist" button doesn't add anything to your wishlist, although it does still take you to your wishlist page.

Whether by accident or by design I'm not sure, but it seems that form_key doesn't work in the URL like most Magento parameters do. It has to be a standard HTTP variable e.g. an input in a form field or added to the query string in a URL like ?form_key=xyz.

On the product view at least, and I think on the list view as well, the wishlist button actually calls `productAddToCartForm.submitLight()`, which means the URL doesn't need the form key at all, since productAddToCartForm already contains it.

How to fix it? As with most things there are a number of ways. You could stop using `$this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product)` and replace it with something like `$this->getStoreUrl('wishlist/index/add/product/'.$_product->getId())` (I haven't tested that so use with caution) or you could override **Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data::getAddUrl** which is how I chose to do it. That way affects all templates etc that try to use an "add to wishlist" url, which could be a good thing or a bad thing. I think good, in this case, but it's up to you.

I **copied Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php from app/code/core to app/code/local** and changed:

```
public function getAddUrl($item)
{
    return $this->getAddUrlWithParams($item);
}
```

to:

```
public function getAddUrl($item)
{
    $productId = null;
    if ($item instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) {
        $productId = $item->getEntityId();
    }
    if ($item instanceof Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item) {
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
    }

    if ($productId) {
        $params = array('product' => $productId);
        return $this->_getUrlStore($item)->getUrl('wishlist/index/add', $params);
    }

    return false;
}
```

...which is simply a copy of the getAddUrlWithParams function with the "params" hard-coded to just the product id.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue. Click on "Add to wishlist" and the page gets redirected to my favorites page with the below mentioned error message.

> We can't add the item to Wish List right now: Cannot add product without stock to wishlist..

Solution: There is no issue with wishlist functionality. By default, Magento 2 ships with the wishlist functionality enabled. In our case, we were using multiple custom sources. You can check this out by visiting

```
Admin-> stores-> sources (if you see apart from the default source)
```

If you wish to disable the default source.

```
Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product stock options -> Set the manage stock = NO
```

[image]

refer https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory.html